# $_GET variable not seen inside if statement

Tags: php, mysqli

I have passed a variable using **GET** to a new page and will like to insert the value into a table in my database but it is saying undefined variable **$exex**. I tried to echo it inside the 'submit' if statement but it is not seen there either. It only echo the variable inside the isset GET if statement.

Below is the code:

```
<?php

session_start();
include "includes/connec.inc.php";

if (isset($_GET['exid'])){
    $exex=$_GET['exid'];
}


 $sql = "SELECT id FROM eaouser WHERE email = '" . $_SESSION['email'] . "'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$eaofid=$row['id'];


if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if (isset($_POST['feedbacks'])){
        $feedback = $_POST['feedbacks'];
        if (!empty($feedback)){

            $INSERT = "INSERT Into feedback (exfid,eaofid,comment) values(?,?,?)";
                $stmt = $conn->prepare($INSERT);
                $stmt->bind_param("iis", $exex, $eaofid,  $feedback);
                $stmt->execute();
                if ($stmt==TRUE){
                echo "<script> alert('Feedback sent!');
                window.location='feedback.php'
                    </script>";
            }else{
                echo "<script> alert('Error sending feedback!');
                window.location='feedback.php'
                    </script>";
            }

        }else{
                echo "<script> alert('Feedback form is empty!');
                window.location='feedback.php'
                    </script>";
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="panel-body">
                <form method="POST" action="feedback.php">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Comment on the experiment:</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="feedbacks" cols="142" rows="5" placeholder="Type here..."></textarea>
                        <br>
                        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" style="background-color: purple;color: white">Send feedback</button>
                    </div>
                </form>

        </div>
```

Comment: How have you confirmed that the variable is being defined?  In your first `if` block, echo the contents of `$exex` after you set it.  Echo it again immediately after the `if` block.  Do you see both values output?  If not, what do you see?  If it's not being set, why do you think it should be?  What's the URL used to access this code?

Comment: @David It echo the variable after setting but only inside the first if block. After the block it says undefined variable. Here is the URL: http://localhost/ProjectEthics/feedback.php?exid=3

Comment: It’s unlikely that a GET and POST is happening at the same time, so you need to include the value of the get variable into the posted form to have it available in the submission. (Or you can add it to the URL but that kind of mixing is ugly)

Comment: @Suleiman: And that's the URL being POSTed to?  It's certainly not impossible to have GET parameters in a POST, it's just uncommon and often a sign of a misunderstanding.  Can you show the HTML which is invoking this request?

Comment: @David I have updated the code with the html and the sql request i used in obtaining the other variable.

Comment: @eckes can you please check the html code i updated. Its a simple form that submits comment but i want it to insert it together with respective id of the user.

Comment: @Suleiman: `action="feedback.php"` - The form's SUBMIT action does not have the URL value you're looking for.  So it's not really clear what you're expecting here.  The value defintiely *won't* be set when posting the form, but that's the only time you're looking for it.

Comment: @David I remove "feedback.php" and submitted the form to it's self action=" '' .

Comment: Soo... Where is `exid` supposed to be send? Its not in the form, not as input and not as a part of the action attribute...

Comment: declare variable '$exex' before if condition at the top, something like : $exex = 0;